# How to Compare Sales of Trial Stores to Control Stores in Power BI

Tags: python, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop, ab-testing, powerbi-custom-visuals

I am trying to compare the sales of trial stores to control stores in Power BI. I have attached the [code](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1SLkKGB5DaFjqqPNa00dP72MFJo0OpehZ?pli=1#scrollTo=Total_Sales_store_77_) that I am using to do this, but I am not able to achieve the same visualization on Power BI as I can in Python.

Here are some additional details about the problem:

I am using the following data:

1. Trial stores: 77, 86, 87
2. Control stores: 233, 155, 237

I am trying to create a visualization that shows the difference in sales between the trial stores, control store, and other stores
I am able to create this visualization in Python, but I am not able to do the same in Power BI.

I tried to create a visualization in Power BI that shows the difference in sales between the trial stores, control stores and other stores. I expected the visualization to show a line chart with 3 lines, one for the trial stores, one for the control stores and one for the other stores. This should show the difference in sales between the 3 groups of stores.

However, the visualization that I created in Power BI did not show the difference in sales between the 3 groups of stores.

[Here is the visual I'm trying to manipulate in Power BI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcpiZ.png)